# Ruby on Rails: No such file or directory - bs_fetch:open_current_file:open (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Have a problem during creating a file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        16: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
        15: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        14: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        13: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        12: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.3.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        11: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.3.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
        10: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
         9: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
         8: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
         7: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
         6: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `tap'
         5: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:137:in `block in perform'
         4: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
         3: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
         2: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:85:in `load_iseq'
         1: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:60:in `fetch'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:60:in `fetch': No such file or directory - bs_fetch:open_current_file:open (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Please, help me with this issue :)

Comment: You haven’t defined the issue. Your first order of business is to better learn how to ask questions on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should start with posting the relevant code that is producing this error